# Looking for a cloud type replacement for local FTP and e-mail file transfer

Tags: online-storage, file-sharing

I've have done some research and a found a lot out there:

**Internal FTP / PHP web based file transfer**

This works ok, I've been using it for a while but I am finding that I spend to much time with security and cleanup. I've decided that I don't really want all kinds of doors on my internal network open to the internet. I want to let someone else, hopefully more qualified them me, handle security and maintenance.

**Torrent & P2P**

I'd love to use torrents or p2p but a client install is something I want to avoid for the sake of my non-computer savvy customers.

**megaupload**

Requires an account signup in order for my customers to send files to me.

**Box.net**

Nice, but it centers around an internal network of specific users. My user base is going to change from day to day depending on which customers I need to share files with. Box.net would break me a $15/user.

**Dropbox**

Requires a client install

**drop.io**

Requires an account setup to upload.

All I want to require my customers to do is type or cut  & paste a URL (which I supply), enter a username and password (which I supply), then click a download or upload button.

No client install, no account signup, no confusing menus, and no ungodly per/user charges.  I want the files to be private per user and to expire after a specific time.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything that does exactly what you want, but I recently came across [AirDropper](https://www.airdropper.com/), which let's you request files by email, and the users don't have to sign up for anything. They just upload the file and it will be dropped in your Dropbox.

Comment: Interesting!  This is the first one I have found that's even close.  I'd give you and up arrow, but I'm not cool enough yet. :)

Thank you!

Comment: Nope, the customer needs an account and a client install to get files from me.  :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the creators of AirDropper. We're still thinking through enabling transfer the other direction. If you drop us a line on our contact form I'd be happy to let you know when we've implemented it. http://www.airdropper.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Click2Copy](http://www.click2copy.com/). There is no account required and you can protect your file with a password. They also have some nice features like resuming.

But you should notice that this is not a file hoster. Your file is sent directly to the recipient which means you both have to be online during the transmission.

Answer (score 0):

[ShareFile](http://www.sharefile.com/) is a great service. I use it in my business. $30 (or $40, can't remember) per month for 2 employees and unlimited clients. Easy user set up too.