# Web write-only drop box

Tags: webapp-rec, file-sharing, hosting, anonymous

Does anyone know of a web app that allows you to create folder where anonymous users can upload content and other authenticated users can view and download the documents? Box.net and Dropbox (ironically) don't seem to allow this.

The context, if anyone cares, is an anonymous staff evaluation that is managed by a committee. I need all the staff to upload their document, and the members of the committee to be able to retrieve them. I would rather not do this via e-mail. Most of the people who will be using this are not power users, so just setting up a folder on an FTP server without a browser-based UI is not an option.

Comment: This question: [Looking for a cloud type replacement for local FTP and e-mail file transfer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/looking-for-a-cloud-type-replacement-for-local-ftp-and-e-mail-file-transfer/5870#5870) might have something useful.

Comment: [Allow an anonymous person to upload to my Dropbox folder](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24731/354)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most document management systems will allow this sort of configuration. Specifically [OpenDocMan](http://www.opendocman.com/) supports this, and I expect that [DocMgr](http://www.docmgr.org/) would as well.

Answer (score 0):

[ZendTo](http://zend.to/) may do what you want, or you might have a look at [Moodle](http://moodle.org/), which is a virtual learning Environment but one of its features is for students to submit files/documents for review by designated course leaders.

Answer (score 0):

[Dropbox Forms](http://www.jotform.com/dropbox/) from JotForm looks like it would solve this problem. You can create a form that will allow someone to upload a file to a `JotForm\Send a File` directory under your Dropbox account. If they filled out the form you'll also get a PDF with information from the form.

[[Lifehacker review](http://lifehacker.com/#!5782180/dropbox-forms-is-the-easiest-way-to-let-anyone-send-a-file-to-your-dropbox-account)]

Answer (score 0):

I set up [GoFileDrop](http://www.gofiledrop.com/), and it seems decent if you need to use Google Docs (though I'm not sure that it supports uploading to subfolders -- only a folder in your root folder).

Answer (score 0):

Using http://SendToMyCloud.com, you can create an upload page for your Dropbox account, that allows users to upload directly to your Dropbox account without having an account, themselves.

FWIW, this also works with Google Drive accounts.