# Allow an anonymous person to upload to my Dropbox folder

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to allow an anonymous person to upload to my Dropbox folder?

If it is possible and someone wants to upload data to my public folder, can I limit the size of the file or the folder?

Comment: This is now a Dropbox feature called **File Requests** see: https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2015/06/introducing-file-requests/ (can't answer question as it's protected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No third party can upload anything to your Public folder of Dropbox by default.

However, you can create a [JotForm's Dropbox upload form](http://jotform.com/dropbox/) to send files there. You will then need to embed the form into a webpage & host the webpage somewhere. If you don't have web hosting, you can put it into your Public folder of Dropbox since the page is static. The Dropbox link is hard to remember so you can create a "pretty" Bit.ly link, such as `bit.ly/Files4DragonSlay3r`, and give it out to people.

There are 2 limits in the free version: 100MB of monthly transfer and 100 submissions. There's another universal limit: 50MB per file uploaded.

In case you aren't proficient with HTML, here's template code for the webpage to embed the upload form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My upload form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    REPLACE THIS WITH THE EMBED CODE FROM JOTFORM
  </body>
</html>
```

Open Notepad (or other simple text editor but **not Word, WordPerfect, WordPad, Pages, etc**), paste the code into it, then click `Save As` and name the file `dropbox-upload.html` or whatever you like as long as it ends in `.html`. Then move the file into Public.

Answer (score 3):

[DBInbox](http://dbinbox.com/) is the best solution I've found by far. Simple multiple file upload totally anonymous and without having to register to a website.

Better than JotForm (which by the way didn't work for me).

Comment: [Lifehacker has a review](http://lifehacker.com/dbinbox-gives-your-dropbox-account-an-inbox-anyone-can-1071910516).

Answer (score 1):

You can allow anonymous people to upload to your dropbox by following the steps listed [here](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?page=2&id=3525#post-122456)

For posterity:

```
$uploader = new DropboxUploader('mysecret@domain.com', 'neverguesspswd'); 
$uploader->upload($tmpFile, $_POST['dest']);
```

However, you should follow the advice from the same thread [post before that](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=3525#post-24448):

> that's very flimsy security-wise, you're opening yourself up to all
>   sorts of crap. not to mention people could effectively DoS your quota
>   or upload pirated material, or what not.
>
> There's plenty of file sending/hosting services, use those.

Comment: _There's plenty of file sending/hosting services, use those._ - Any suggestions on one that does allow anonymous uploading? I have been having a hard time finding one.

Answer (score 0):

An instructor told me about http://dropitto.me/, which looks like a viable option, but I'm wary of trying it out since it gains access to my whole Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

This solution gives you lots of control, by allowing you to create your own Dropbox uploader web page, if you have access to a web server you can use.
http://www.ampercent.com/dropbox-uploader-allow-users-upload-files-dropbox-account/

Comment: Are you affiliated with that product? If so, you should disclose it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try EntourageBox, a tool suggested for the same purposes in a SuperUser thread [here](https://superuser.com/a/589068/76898).

Answer (score 0):

Using http://SendToMyCloud.com, you can create an upload page for your Dropbox account, that allows users to upload directly to your Dropbox account without having an account, themselves.

FWIW, this also works with Google Drive accounts.

Also, in interest of full disclosure: I'm affiliated with this project.